# Local Storage in Google Apps Scripts (Forms and Sheets)

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, local-storage, google-forms

> I want to set some value in my local storage (browser) and use it in a
> form.

e.g.:
I open a form, it sees in my LS that my key tells us I am from company X.
I fill in the form, and depending on my key it will send it to a specific sheet for that company
and if it doesn't see any keys, it opens a prompt with the question to fill in the company name (key).

something in the lines of this:

```js
const company = localStorage.key[0].value;

if (! company ) {
  //prompt message
  //set prompt result as key
} else if (company === "X") {
  googleSheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/.../';
} else if (company === "Y") {
  googleSheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/.../';
}
```

1. is this something that is (not)recommended as a practice?
2. How should I approach this?

Comment: It's only available client side.  I use it in chrome snippets all of the time.  I'm not completely sure what your attempting to do but I might use PropertiesService instead.

Comment: What is the context of this? A Workspace Add-on?

Comment: It would be to make a workspace tracker, but for multiple organisations, so I thought about making a script that would look for a key from the user (or set one if there are none) as a selector on what sheet url it needs to send te info to.

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` is only available in the browser. Apps Script is executed in a Google server, and thus it is not available. Apps Script already has an alternative: Properties Service. This allows to have a dictionary of string values for a script, user, or document. In this case you need a user properties. This is how to use it:

```js
const userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties()
userProperties.setProperty('company', companyName)
```

### References

- [Properties Service (Apps Script Guide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)